# The value and address of an array are the same, except when passed to a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void pass_arr(int arr[]);

void pass_arr_test()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    printf( "arr  = %p\n"
            "&arr = %p\n\n", arr, &arr);

    pass_arr(arr);
}

void pass_arr(int arr[])
{
    printf( "passed arr  = %p\n"
            "passed &arr = %p\n\n", arr, &arr);
}
```

---

Output:
arr  = 0x28ccd0
&arr = 0x28ccd0

passed arr = 0x28ccd0
passed &arr = 0x28ccc0

---

Can someone explain why the value and adress of arr points to the same adress when evaluated in the block where arr was created, but when passed the value and adress point to two different adresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in the function **`arr` is actually a pointer**, not an array. Taking the address of a pointer does not yield the same address, the way it does for an array.

Comment: That makes sense!
So by passing an array to a function you actually receive a pointer as the parameter of the function which points to the array but has a unique adress which is the adress of the created pointer.

Comment: @user38541 Almost right. The pointer points to the first element of the array, not to the array itself.

Comment: Ok.
But pointing to the first element of the array is the same as pointing to the array itself (at least that's what I've read..)?

Comment: @user38541 It's not quite the same. Read more about "array pointers".

Answer (score 2):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array<sup>1</sup>.

When you call

```
`pass_arr(arr)`;
```

the expression `arr` is converted from type "5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", or `int *`.

Note that the address of the first element of the array is the address of the array itself; that's why you get the same *value* when you print the results of `arr` and `&arr` int `pass_arr_test`, but remember that the *types* are different; the expression `arr` is converted to type `int *`, but `&arr` has type `int (*)[5]`; this matters for things like pointer arithmetic.

Secondly, in the context of a function prototype, declarations of the form `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are interpreted as `T *a`; `a` is actually declared as a pointer instead of an array.<sup>2</sup>

The important thing to remember is that **arrays are not pointers**.  Rather, in most contexts, array *expressions* are **converted** to pointers as necessary.

---

<sup>1 - [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, ¶ 3</sup>
<sup>2 - [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), ¶ 7</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That is due to `pass by value` semantics where the arr in pass_arr method is a local pointer variable on the stack whose value is the location of the `arr` passed from pass_arr_test method. So, `arr` variable in both pass_arr and pass_arr_test are point to the same location and hence the value is same. Since they are two different pointers, their memory address is different. In case of array definition, arr is just an alias to the start of the array and hence it's location and it's value are the same.